# What options does a Rogue have to tackle Wizard and Cleric party members who are planning betrayal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue

Are there any tricks a high-level rogue can do which can temporarily distract a high-level cleric and/or wizard?

The Situation:

I play a 17th level rogue. I have reason to believe the party's 18th level cleric and 18th level wizard may do a [face-heel turn](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FaceHeelTurn) near the end of the scenario. My rogue has reason to believe this, but also doesn't want to live in a world ruled (well, held hostage) by the cleric and wizard. Presumably the rest of the party doesn't either; at least the paladin.

So basically, I'm wondering if there are any good anti-cleric or anti-wizard strategies or items. Is it a matter of looking over the spells the characters used during the adventure and developing counters, or are there other things which could hobble the casters, at least for a round or two?

Since they are both Tier 1 classes, I won't assume it's possible to beat them. Stalling them might be just enough. (And surviving, if possible.)

Comment: We need rather more details here. Generic rogue versus wizard is different from PvP conflict with known capabilities and habits. What is your specific build? What are the wizard and clerics builds? What actions do they habitually do? What norms for PvP conflict exist within your game? Do you still adventure with them, and do they trust you?

Comment: What are they going to do as part of their face-heel turn? What is the general situation? How long do they have to be distracted, and what do they need to be deterred from doing? (If they need to pick up the Holy Orb, suddenly a spell that can manifest a thousand fake orbs and turn the room into a ballpit might become relevant, for instance.)

Comment: There are a thousand items and strategies to take out a caster, from "stab them in their sleep when they still think you're a friend" on up - this is going to be too unfocused given the limited information available.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't *blatantly* answer in the comments, especially on a closed question, but really, isn't the obvious answer mxyzplk's?  Steal the cleric's holy symbol (while he's asleep, clearly) and let the paladin deal with him (poison the paladin's blade while he's not looking) while you Con poison'd sneak attack the sleeping wizard.  You can, once you confirm the wizard's death, go flank with the paladin to provide more damage, but realize that *slay living* is a Fort save.

Comment: Even that is highly situation-dependent. Heck, we don't even know if they still sleep, or if there will be significant time between when they are expected to turn and when they are still needed. That being said, I'm pretty confident this is actually answerable: distraction is desired, not defeat. With sufficient cash, a lack of "Contingency: Dominate the Rogue" spells active, and either a surprise round or successful bluff, any of the accidentally borked items should win this for even a commoner with appropriate wealth. For instance, Dust of Sneezing and Choking.

Comment: No matter how subtle the wizard, a knife between the shoulder blades will seriously cramp his style. ;)

Comment: @Arkhaic We also don't know anything about the rogue.  Slippery Mind?

Comment: This question closed months ago, but yeah. Or they could have that caster-silencing feat (of course, a prepared wizard can get around pretty much anything if they happen to have the right spells at the time).  The assumption that tier 1 = unbeatable is pretty problematic too.